# How can stop continuous loading when detecting some keywords by using CefSharp

Tags: cefsharp

I am now building an application with a browser, when user enter a URL, my program will first detect the URL will redirect to other link or not. If my program detect the redirect URL contains some keywords, it will stop to load the page and return to the main program.

I already know I have implement IRequestHandler to get the redirect URL, but I don't know how to stop continuous to load the page and save the status and then return back to main program. Please help Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

using System.Threading;

namespace Chrome
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitBrowser();
        }

        private Thread m_ThreadDetect;
        public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        public void InitBrowser()
        {
            var setting = new CefSettings();
            setting.CachePath = "/BrowserCache";
            setting.PersistSessionCookies = true;
            Cef.Initialize(setting);
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.testing.com")
            {
                RequestHandler = new MyRequestHandler()
            };
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(browser);
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        private void button_go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_URL.Text) || textBox_URL.Text.Equals("about:blank"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid URL.");
                textBox_URL.Focus();
                return;
            }

            browser.Load(textBox_URL.Text);
            ///////////////////////////////////////
            //Check whether the browser already catch the keyword in here
             ///////////////////////////
        }

        private void button_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            browser.Find(0, textBox_search.Text, true, false, false);
        }


        private async Task getSource()
        {
            string htmlText = await browser.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CefSharp;
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace Chrome
{
    class MyRequestHandler : IRequestHandler
    {
        public bool CanGetCookies(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            return true;
        }

        public bool CanSetCookie(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, Cookie cookie)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            return true;
        }

        public bool GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IResponseFilter GetResourceResponseFilter(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetResourceResponseFilter");
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            return null;
        }

        public bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool userGesture, bool isRedirect)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();

            Console.WriteLine("OnBeforeBrowse");
            Console.WriteLine("OnBeforeBrowse, isRedirect"+ isRedirect);
            return false;
        }

        public CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            Console.WriteLine("OnBeforeResourceLoad");
            return CefReturnValue.Continue;
        }

        public bool OnCertificateError(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, CefErrorCode errorCode, string requestUrl, ISslInfo sslInfo, IRequestCallback callback)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool OnOpenUrlFromTab(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnPluginCrashed(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string pluginPath)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool OnProtocolExecution(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string url)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool OnQuotaRequest(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, long newSize, IRequestCallback callback)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnRenderProcessTerminated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, CefTerminationStatus status)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnRenderViewReady(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnResourceLoadComplete(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response, UrlRequestStatus status, long receivedContentLength)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnResourceLoadComplete");
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnResourceRedirect(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response, ref string newUrl)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(response.Headers);

            //detect keyword
            if(location.Equals("Redirect"))
            {
                chromiumWebBrowser.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Detect Stop");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done");

            Console.WriteLine("OnResourceRedirect");
            Console.WriteLine(newUrl);
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool OnResourceResponse(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            Console.WriteLine("here");
            return false;
        }

        public bool OnSelectClientCertificate(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, bool isProxy, string host, int port, X509Certificate2Collection certificates, ISelectClientCertificateCallback callback)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `continuous load`? It's not clear what your trying to achieve here.

Comment: I would like to loop if the web page redirect to another page, I would like to load it again

Comment: I still don't understand.